# Automatic sign out after some time of sign in - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using `Devise` for authentication. Now I want to signed out a user after a fixed time of sign in if the user forget to sign out. I know about `timeoutable` of devise. It actually works with inactivity of user. But I need something works with signing in time.

N.B. I found something relative in stackoverflow but they are answered before 3 or 4 years ago. I want to know the best way in Rails 4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use backgound jobs.. After sing-in submit a job with the user as an argument.. and from there check ... the interval.. and sign out once the interval reached..

Comment: Won't it be annoying to users that they are active with the website(doing some work) and you signout them.

Comment: I would suggest not to sign out active users automatically, it would give a bad user experience. Rather you can log them out if they are inactive. In that case you need to simple un-comment `config.timeout_in = 30.minutes` from *config/initializers/devise.rb*

Answer (score 1):

In model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :authenticatable, :timeoutable, :validatable, :timeout_in => 20.minutes
end
```

**OR**

devise.rb:

```
config.timeout_in = 20.minutes
```